# Acess DCT coefficients and Quantization values with libJPEG

Tags: c, image-processing, jpeg, libjpeg, dct

I am reading a bitmap file and compressing it into a JPEG file using the libJPEG library, simple enough. But now I would like to write each of the intermediate stages, ie DCT and Quantization to a file during compression. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the help files that come with libjpeg explain how to access the DCT coefficients.  You can then expand the example.c file that comes with it to do your compression and examine DCT coefficients while you're at it.